# Remove content and append class with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to use a proprietary cms blog that renders it's "summary marker" that contains

1. an elipsis
2. a dynamic changing link (so the link is always different)
3. static text that says: Click here to read more.

This is how the summary marker currently renders on a page:

```
<p>Content goes here....<a href="example.htm">Click here to read more.</a></p>
<p>More content goes here....<a href="anothertest.htm">Click here to read more.</a></p>
<p>Content goes here....<a href="helloworld.htm">Click here to read more.</a></p>
```

Meanwhile, I would like to control the summary marker with some jquery so I'm not restricted to its rigid display by:

1. removing each `ellipsis`
2. appending a `class` ONLY after the `href` that contained the ellipsis, so it doesn't update other links on the page.

This would be the much desired expected result.

```
<p>Content goes here.<a href="example.htm" class="readmore">Click here to read more.</a></p>
<p>More content goes here.<a href="anothertest.htm" class="readmore">Click here to read more.</a>
<p>Content goes here.<a href="helloworld.htm" class="readmore">Click here to read more.</a>
```

Thanks so much for your help in advance!

This is what I got, which is bad I know

```
$("p").html("...").remove:after.attr(".readmore").attr("href"));
```

Comment: So that what or who "*doesn't update other links on the page*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var textNode = $(this).find('a:last-child').addClass('readmore')[0].previousSibling;

    textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(/\.{3}\s*$/, '');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sH2eA/

Comment: I think this need a fine-print somewhere describing that it would change unexpected elements also

Comment: should replace last `...` only; not _all_;

Comment: I found this does not work in IE8, the error returned 'textContent' is null or not an object. This did work in IE9, firefox, chrome.